# deleting email pattern, keeping the rest using grep, awk or sed?

Tags: regex, email, sed, grep, pattern-matching

I got this plain text from wich I want to delete all email adresses (or replace by E). I want to keep everything else in the text file. The email adresses can be followed by a space, colon, semicolon, question or exclamation mark. I work with gnuwin and tried grep but didn't got the right result

```
grep -Eiv "\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b" in.txt > out.txt
```

This removes every line containing the email pattern. I want only the emails gone.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For substitution use `sed` not `grep`:

```
sed -r 's/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b//Ig' in.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: Combining both answers (frhd and anubhava) I got the code I wan't. "sed -r "s/([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})//g" in.txt > out.txt" Every email is removed from the tex file!

Comment: This (edited) solution works. I suppose it had to do with case sensivity. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Combining both answers (frhd and anubhava) I get the code I wan't.

```
sed -r "s/([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})//g" in.txt > out.txt
```

It removes every email from the text file

Comment: This is the pretty much same solution I posted, please don't post as another answer. If my answer helped you you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: And how it is different from my answer other than adding `a-z` in charatcer class?

Comment: Different in that his version works? :) I have written my regex version from scratch, and yes, you're right, the only difference (apart from using `( )` as word boundaries) is making it case insensitive with `a-z`. I can see why bertje posted another answer: your solution didn't work and instead of correcting your's, he posted another one. He will learn.

Comment: A smaller and more compact sed will be `sed -r 's/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b//Ig'` for ignore case substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Regex version:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9\._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})[\ \:\;\?\!]?
```

https://regex101.com/r/qJ2eG7/1

Comment: seems that the last part [\ \:\;\?\!]? is not needed for my text file as long as the email adress is not followed bij alphanumeric characters. So your code "([a-zA-Z0-9\._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})"  can be implemented in the code below (thanks)